# SQL Query to split number in a given interval

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a number (say 100,000). I want to split this number between given intervals of 15,000 and 19,900. I expect the results to be between 15,000 and 19,900. I need an SQL Query/Function to do this task.

Example: 
If I need to split 100,000 between intervals of 15,000 and 19,900 the results should be like this:

```
15100.00
16750.00
19365.22
18254.85
15987.65
14542.28
```

Please see that the sum of all these values is equal to 100,000
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some examples? It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you add an example of how you want it to work?

Comment: What are the "results" you're expecting?

Comment: I assume 3x15.000, 1x15.200 & 2x19.900 would quallify for their sum being 100.000?

Comment: I have modified the question.

Comment: @Nagesh, your last sample from your example doesn't fit within your boundary. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the last selected number does not need to be within the range you specified (as per your example), following would return some random numbers summing to the total given.

```
DECLARE @LowBound FLOAT
DECLARE @HighBound FLOAT
DECLARE @Total FLOAT

SET @LowBound = 15000
SET @HighBound = 19900
SET @Total = 100000

;WITH q AS (
  SELECT  [Value] = @LowBound  + (@HighBound - @LowBound) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) 
          , [RunningTotal] = CAST(0.00 AS FLOAT)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  [Value] = @LowBound  + (@HighBound - @LowBound) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))  
          , [RunningTotal] = CAST((q.[RunningTotal] + [Value]) AS FLOAT)
  FROM    q          
  WHERE   q.[RunningTotal] < @Total
)
SELECT  CASE  WHEN [RunningTotal] < @Total 
              THEN [Value] 
              ELSE [Value] - ([RunningTotal] - @Total)
        END AS Result
FROM    (
          SELECT  [Value]
                  , [RunningTotal] = [Value] + [RunningTotal]
          FROM    q
        ) q
WHERE   [RunningTotal] - [Value] <= @Total
```

Comment: Giving you credits for something that seems completely without meaning to solve :)

Comment: @cairnz, lol. OP doesn't seem to visit SO frequently but he might indeed shed some light on the *why* of his question.

Comment: @Nagesh, no problem but as @cairnz said, why do you need this using SQL? This would have been easier to do in any procedural language.